# OED Appeals: Origin of "bimble"

Tags: etymology, verbs, dialects, oed-appeals, military

The OED has made a [public appeal](http://public.oed.com/the-oed-needs-you-announcing-the-new-oed-appeals/) for help in tracing the history of some English words, [including](http://public.oed.com/appeals/bimble/):

> ### bimble
>
> verb *earlier than 1983*
>
> The word *bimble*, meaning ‘to move at a leisurely pace’, is sometimes said to have originated amongst British soldiers serving in the Falklands, and much of our early evidence supports this. However, one of our correspondents, who grew up in the north-east of England in the mid-20th century, says he remembers the word *bimble* from his childhood there. We’re looking for earlier evidence of the word to uncover the real story: is *bimble* a military coinage of recent vintage, or a north-eastern English dialect term with a longer history?
>
> Here is the earliest example currently in OED for the verb bimble:
>
> > **1983 R. McGowan & J. Hands *Don’t cry for Me, Sergeant Major* iv. 81 When the Marines moved at a slower pace they were ‘bimbling’.**
>
> Can you help us trace the origins of this word?

Comment: See J.R.R. Tolkien: "Tales and Songs of Bimble Bay"

Comment: As noted by tchrist, "bimble occurs in Tolkien's poem cycle "Tales and Songs of Bimble Bay" This was apparently by Tolkien's (ex-OED person himself)visit to Filey and the coastal part of the north riding of Yorkshire. is their any chance the regional dialect might be the source of bimble?

Comment: We used Bimbling or Bimble all the time when I was at my 1st RAF Posting in 1979/80 at RAF Honnington, it was in use at other stations as well.

Comment: W W Jacobs wrote a sequel to the better known "Three Men in a Boat" called "Three Men on the Bummel" about the same three  characters touring rather aimlessly around Germany at the turn of the 20th century. He explains that "Bummel" is a word for gentle, more or less aimless travelling. I wonder whether "Bummel" is the origin of "Bimble" and also, possibly, of the American word "bum"

Answer (score 5):

From [*The First Saint Omnibus: An Anthology of Saintly Adventures*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1558820604) (1939), page 269:

> But the Duchess starts *bimbling* And wambling and wimbling And
>   threatens to wallop his ducal behind;

Such a lovely phrase.

Comment: Good find! Which story in the [anthology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_Templar#Omnibus_editions) is it from? Is it in "The Million Pound Day" (from *The Holy Terror*)?

Comment: Whilst attempting to confirm the source, I found another *bimbling* in Leslie Charteris's *The Holy Terror*. Or rather the author [Neil Gaiman](https://twitter.com/neilhimself/status/16424111844) did a couple of years ago: *Per http://bit.ly/9SPhiT Bimble's 2007. "The Duke of Fortezza/Frequently gets a/Nimpulse to go bimbling off- " is 1932 http://bit.ly/bAzs5t*

Comment: Thanks @icecurtain, I've submitted all this to the [OED](http://public.oed.com/appeals/bimble/#comment-718093428).

Comment: Is there more context that makes it clear what "bimbling" means in this passage?  It doesn't really sound like the Duchess is "moving at a leisurely pace" so maybe you have found another meaning.  Or is it just being used as a nonsense word?

Comment: The OED [replies](http://public.oed.com/appeals/bimble/#comment-814256783): We've now investigated these potential
antedatings from Charteris. As it turns out, they refer to the same passage.
The promising phrase ‘to go bimbling off’ is a misquotation; the original reads
‘to go blithering off’. In the phrase ‘the Duchess starts bimbling and wambling
and wimbling,’ bimble appears to be a fanciful nonsense word with
uncertain sense, and we can’t be certain that it represents the same word which
later came to mean ‘to wander or amble’.

Comment: And the full [passage](http://public.oed.com/appeals/bimble/#comment-814256783): 1932 L. Charteris Holy Terror ii. vii. 181
The Duke of Fortezza Quite frequently gets a Nimpulse to go blithering off on
the blind, But the Duchess starts bimbling And wambling and wimbling And
threatens to wallop his ducal behind; And her Ladyship's threats are So fierce
that he sweats a Nd just sobs as he pets her With tearful regrets—Ah! The Duke
of Fortezza Is changing his mind.

Answer (score 3):

[Bill S](http://public.oed.com/appeals/bimble/#comment-696478727) found a *bimble* as a noun in 1980 which the OED has verified:

> Snippett from "Roots of England", John Miller, Sid Waddell 1980
>
> "Most said that getting their 'wets' [drinks] meant little involvement with the locals, but one Yorkshire seaman had weighed up the situation: 'When Jack [a sailor] gets a run ashore here, he's generally on the bimble [a night out] right?"

(More verbs before 1983 and nouns before 1980 still welcome!)

Answer (score 3):

I was very  interested to read above that there's a strong Falklands link to this word. I lived in Stanley, FI (as a civilian) from 2003-2007. Since returning to the UK I've used the word without thinking about it. Twice recently I've had people ask me what it means/where it comes from. I was surprised, because I had thought it was universal, but on reflection realised I'd picked it up in the Falklands. I looked it up, to back up my explanation of what it meant, and came across this page.

So - it's still used in the Falklands, by the local population, and more common there than it is in the UK. Means a little trip, an aimless wander or explore. Could be on foot, or in the Land Rover, on or off road.

Comment: astounding information!  awesome...

Answer (score 2):

The word as used in the following excerpt doesn't involve wandering in a leisurely way, but there is something quite unexpected in this instance of *bimbling* from Sam Lonschein, [*My 83 Years: The Memoirs of a Veteran Zionist*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Bh5CAAAAIAAJ&q=%22After+ten+minutes+of+bimbling%22&dq=%22After+ten+minutes+of+bimbling%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ezN1Vc-APY7zoATt5IGoBA&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA) (1967) [combined snippets]:

> The only bulletin notice in front of the building had his name written up by hand. The few friends whom I had sold about six tickets looked at me with suspicion. We sat down. Soon the artist appeared. Bowed graciously and sat down at the old piano in the middle of the stage. He threw his head backward and began to play something, but none of us understood what it was. After ten minutes of **bimbling** and moving his fingers over the instrument he stopped with a bang and stood up. There was little hand clapping from the first row. (All his relatives were in that row). He went backstage, then came out again and this time he played a Rumanian popular piece. It was a complete fiasco. The few people (strangers) walked out in disgust.
>
> A few weeks later when I saw my printer friend he told me that Conrad Bercovici was not a pianist at all. The concert was arranged by his family to get together a few dollars as he had come over penniless from France to try his luck as a novelist in the English language. He also informed me that the "Tageblatt" had bought a story from him for $10.00 which they were now translating into Yiddish to be printed in some future number of the paper.
>
> This is the story of the well known gypsy story novelist, Conrad Bercivici, who became famous in later years as a fiction story writer.

In this instance, *bimbling* may be a typo for *bumbling*, or it may be a neologism of the author's to describe a kind of aimless but exaggerated attempt to play an instrument without really playing it at all. In any case it seems highly unlikely to have had any influence on the emergence of *bimble* in the Falkland Islands 15 years later.

Answer (score 1):

I recall using this word in the Royal Navy in the 1970s — prior to the Falklands Conflict.

Comment: What did you use _after_ the conflict?

Comment: Thanks. [Others recall](http://public.oed.com/appeals/bimble/) using it in the 1970s in the Royal Marines and RAF. What the OED ideally needs is some kind of recorded evidence of its use. Obviously it's a lot harder with this sort of slang, but perhaps it's in a notebook or diary entry somewhere. Anyway, anecdotal evidence is still helpful to piece together the origin.

Answer (score 1):

I have always understood it to be an (unofficial) military acronym - Basic Infantry Manoeuvre But Lacking Effort. (BIMBLE)

Answer (score 0):

I remember this word from childhood in Seventies and Eighties. My Mum used to use it to mean a little fun walk or an outing. She was born and brought up in Bury, Lancs (she was born 1944).
The military connection interests me as her Dad served in the army in WW2 in France.

Comment: This anecdote counts as hearsay; it is, unfortunately, insufficient for supporting **evidence**.

Answer (score -2):

I have an old photo of a black & white kitten called "Bimble 2" dating from early 1900's - probably the Victorian era.  The "2" suggests that there was an even earlier cat called "Bimble".

Comment: Are you suggesting a connection between the kitten's name and the word for a leisurely wander?